# iAd Code in WWDC Session 503 does not work

Tags: iad, ios9

Recommendation is as follows for AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    return true
}
```

Exception is:

> 2015-08-16 10:51:54.555 troubleiAd[46052:7032519] +[UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10e478870
>   2015-08-16 10:51:54.558 troubleiAd[46052:7032519] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10e478870'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc239b5 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ec16deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>     2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc2bedd +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>     3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb799fa ___forwarding_** + 970
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb795a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>     5   troubleiAd                          0x000000010ca3cf04 _TFC10troubleiAd11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 100
>     6   troubleiAd                          0x000000010ca3d023 _TToFC10troubleiAd11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 179

change uiviewcontroller to GameViewContoller:

> 2015-08-16 11:02:08.100 troubleiAd[46190:7052666] +[troubleiAd.GameViewController prepareInterstitialAds]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1035aa5f0
>   2015-08-16 11:02:08.103 troubleiAd[46190:7052666] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[troubleiAd.GameViewController prepareInterstitialAds]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1035aa5f0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010378b9b5 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010577edeb objc_exception_throw + 48
>     2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103793edd +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>     3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036e19fa ___forwarding_** + 970
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036e15a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>     5   troubleiAd                          0x00000001035a4f54 _TFC10troubleiAd11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 100
>     6   troubleiAd                          0x00000001035a5073 _TToFC10troubleiAd11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 179

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have not added the iAd Framework to your project.

1. Go to your Target
2. Build Phases
3. Link Binary With Libraries
4. Click the **+**
5. Search for iAd
6. Select **iAd.framework**
7. Click Add

[image: Import iAd GIF]
**[Fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnXDQ.gif)**

Answer (score 0):

Just create a global variable:

```
var interstitial = ADInterstitialAd()
```

iAd framework will be linked automatically.